# Adding custom UIViewController with UITableView as a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create custom UIViewController with a UITableView, load the UIViewController using a xib file and add the view as a subview to another UIView.

The hierarchy is like this:

- UIViewController

  - UIView << add custom UIViewController's view
  - UIView
  - UIView

Here's my xib view hierarchy and settings:

- UIView

  - UITableView

Connection in IB:

- File's Owner:CustomTableViewController
- Outlets:

  - view connected to UIView
  - tableView connected to File's Owner
  - delegate connected to File's Owner
  - datasource connected to File's Owner

I have both UITableDataSource and UITableDelegate implemented.
When i tried to add the view as a subview, it crashed ...

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      CustomTableViewController* controller = [[CustomTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomTableView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];      
      [self.viewContainer addSubview:controller.view];   
  }
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Tell us more about the crash.

Comment: It stops in main() with this message: Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". Thanks

Comment: Sounds like something isn't retained that should be.  Set an exception breakpoint and turn on zombies to help look for it.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I don't have instance variable that holds CustomTableViewController and that's why I'm getting the exception. I added a property and init with 'self.controller = [[CustomTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomTableView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];' That fix the problem. Thanks again Peter.

Comment: Np.  I added it as an answer so we can wrap this question up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds Like something is not retained that should be.  Set up an exception breakpoint and turn on zombies to find it.  See askers results above.