# Proper sizing of UIViewController's view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

After dealing with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706989/adding-custom-uiviewcontroller-with-uitableview-as-a-subview) so many hours without any luck, I'm trying different approach by creating views programmatically in my `UIViewController`'s loadView. I have `UIToolbar` and `UITableView` in my `UIViewController` but I have trouble with the sizing when adding the view as another `UIView`'s subview. Here's what I got so far:

In my custom UIViewController' loadView:

```
{

    [super loadView];

    //this doesn't seem right!?!?
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300);

    //create the Tool Bar
    self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45.01)];

    [self.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [self.toolbar setAutoresizesSubviews:TRUE];
    [self.toolbar setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)]; 

    // create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
    NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    //create buttons
    UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
    bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:bi];

    //add buttons to the toolbar
    [self.toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    //add toolbar to the view
    [self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];


    //create UITableView
    //a better way setting to set the frame!?!?
    UITableView* listTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
                                                                           self.toolbar.bounds.size.height, 
                                                                           self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                                                           self.view.bounds.size.height - self.toolbar.bounds.size.height) 
                                                          style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [listTable setAutoresizesSubviews:TRUE];
    [listTable setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [listTable setDataSource:self];
    [listTable setDelegate:self];

    self.table = listTable;
    [self.view addSubview:listTable];
}
```

In rootViewController's loadView():

```
{
    [super loadView];

    controller = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
    [self.customView addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller.view setAutoresizesSubviews:TRUE];
}
```

You can see the screenshot here:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/112841433450419935389/albums/5693241484889252817/5693241483569881554

I'm new with this, other than getting the sizing correct, am i on the right track?

Many thanks.

---

Edit:

I'm trying to create a view like this

- UIViewController

  - UINavigationBar
  - UIView << on the left, custom UIViewController with UIToolbar and UITableView
  - UIView << on the right, same as above

This one is close to what I'm trying to do except that I will have two UITableView and no segmented buttons.
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/112841433450419935389/albums/5693241484889252817/5693260341279558818

Answer (score 0):

From what I can deduct of your code you want a UITableView to fill all the screen except for a bar on the upper part of the screen. (Usually a UIToolBar is on the bottom of the screen)

If you take a [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and put it as the rootViewController of a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you will have a lot of nice behaviour and sizing for free.

In a `UINavigationController` the bar at the top of the screen is the `navigationBar` and you can have a `toolBar` at the bottom with this call if you want :

```
- (void)setToolbarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
```

And the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) is a good place to look into.

Comment: Vince, please see edit above. I can't use UINavigationController because I need two UITableView and each of them will have their own toolbar.

Comment: @Eric, ok, from your edit I see that you want to place UIViewControllers inside other UIViewController, unless you are on an iPad using UISplitViewController, that can lead you to trouble. Usually it's one UIViewController per screen.

Answer (score 0):

You've made some assumptions that are contrary to the way UIViewControllers are expected to be used and I think that mismatch is at the root of your confusion.

UIViewControllers do not normally manage the size of their own root view. Their view is resized by it's container. That means that the window or a container view controller like a UINavigationController (or a custom container view controller using the iOS 5 APIs) manages the frame of the controller's view.

Attempting to adjust a controller's frame is `-loadView` is unlikely to have an effect because the view's frame may be reset when the view is later added to the window or parent controller's view. Similarly a controller shouldn't adjust it's own view's frame after the view has been loaded because that might compete with its parent view's `-layoutSubviews` behavior.

Instead I think you want a view controller whose view contains both the UITableView and UINavigation bar you want to display. As @VinceBurn suggested it sounds like you want behavior a UINavigationController already provides.

Comment: Jonah, thanks for the answer. If I'm setting up the views programmatically, I'm assuming I need to set the layout of the views first before the root view gets added to the parent controller's view, am I correct? If so, where can I do this?

Comment: You can layout subviews when the root view is constructed in `-loadView` you just need to be prepared for that root view's frame to change later by setting an appropriate autoresizing mask or implementing `-layoutSubviews` on a custom UIView subclass.

Please also be aware that you're likely to hit unexpected behavior  if you nest UIViewControllers prior to iOS 5 or do not use the child view controller methods iOS 5 provides. I tried to cover this in more detail at http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Comment: thanks for the advice and sharing your post. I just started with iOS development and I'm having hard time understanding how the view controllers work.